# Get column index as constant value

Tags: c#, datagridview, switch-statement

Currently i am having code like this inside `dataGridView1_CellValidating` event:

```
if(e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["FIRST"].Index)
{
    // Some code
}
else if(e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Second"].Index)
{
    // Some code
}
else if(e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Third"].Index)
{
    // Some code
}
```

And it is like this because i cannot use it in switch statement like:

```
switch(e.ColumnIndex)
{
    case dataGridView.Columns["First"].Index:
        break;
    case dataGridView.Columns["Second"].Index:
        break;
    case dataGridView.Columns["Third"].Index:
        break;
}
```

returns me error on `case` line `Expecting constant value`.

**So how can i make this work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch statement is complaining because the “case” portion of the statement “requires” a “CONSTANT” value. The statement `dataGridView.Columns["First"].Index` will always return the same value… unless you move the column… which you can do. This is why the compiler is going to look at the retuned value from `dataGridView.Columns["First"].Index` as NOT a “constant”.

This makes sense in the fact that the “column index” for the column named “First” could be at ANY column index in the grid… Hence the error.

A possible solution is to grab the current columns “Name” string value then switch off the column “Name” like below.

```
string columnName = dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
switch (columnName) {
  case "First":
    MessageBox.Show("Cell Validated is in 'FIRST' column");
    break;
  case "Second":
    MessageBox.Show("Cell Validated is in 'Second' column");
    break;
  case "Third":
    MessageBox.Show("Cell Validated is in 'Third' column");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thinking out of the box. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use switch you can make use of pattern matching in switch case

PS: For C# 7.0 or above

```
switch(e.ColumnIndex)
{
    case var _ when (dataGridView.Columns["First"].Index == e.ColumnIndex):
        break;
    case var _ when (dataGridView.Columns["Second"].Index == e.ColumnIndex):
        break;
    case var _ when (dataGridView.Columns["Third"].Index == e.ColumnIndex):
        break;
}
```

Comment: @AleksaRistic What is version of C# you are using ? Pattern Matching is part of c# from 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you first make constant values and assign dataGridView.Columns["First"].Index to it.
For example:

```
int a = {given index}
const int IndexOfFirstCol = dataGridView.Columns["First"].Index;
const int IndexOfSecCol = dataGridView.Columns["Second"].Index;
```

then,

```
switch(a)
{
    case IndexOfFirstCol:
      //do smth
      break;
    case IndexOfSecCol:
      //do smth
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have another approach, using a `Dictionnary` (from the namespace `System.Collections.Generic`) of methods built in such way

The key is the index of the column in the datagridview ("First", "Second" ...)

The value is a Delegate to the method to do (what replaces your `// some code` in each if/else if

In example :

```
/*
 * This example is written for console application, that can be tested easily.
 * The logic can be rewritten for WinForm
 */

static void TheFirstCase()
{
    //This should be replaced by the differents actions you want to do
    Console.WriteLine("first case"); 
}

static void TheSecondtCase()
{
    Console.WriteLine("second case");
}

static void TheThirdCase()
{
    Console.WriteLine("third case");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, Delegate> MyDic = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>
    {
        //If you need parameters in the TheFirstCase(), use new Action<TypeOfTheFirstParam, TypeOfTheSecondParam, ...>(TheFirstCase)
        //If your Method needs to return something, use Func instead of Action
        { "First", new Action(TheFirstCase) }, 
        { "Second", new Action(TheSecondtCase) },
        { "Third", new Action(TheThirdCase) }
    };
    // in your question, this is e.ColumnIndex
    var ValueInColIndex = 42;

    // in your question, this is dataGridView.Columns
    var DataGridViewDatas = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {  "First", 0 },
        {  "Second", 42 },
        {  "Third", 69 }
    };

    foreach (var MyAction in MyDic)
    {
        if (DataGridViewDatas[MyAction.Key] == ValueInColIndex)
        {
            MyAction.Value.DynamicInvoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs :

> second case

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use pattern matching from C# 7.0, there is also another way by using dictonaries where your keys are functions checking the conditions (cases) and the values are the actions you want to perform. For your code it would look like:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    var caseDictionary = new Dictionary<Func<bool>, Action>()
    {
        { () => (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["First"].Index), () => {  MessageBox.Show("First");}},
        { () => (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Second"].Index), () => { MessageBox.Show("Second");}},
        { () => (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Third"].Index), () => { MessageBox.Show("Third");}}
    };
    caseDictionary.Where(caseRecord => caseRecord.Key()).Select(action => action.Value).FirstOrDefault()?.Invoke();
}
```

You could of course declare the Dictionary in your constructor and just call it in the `CellValidating` event.